# Mail Sending Failed error when sending email in php

Tags: php

When i send mail php from my server it works fine.But when i placed the code in my client server.it shows mail sending failed.what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP server does not configured for [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). Basically [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function uses sendmail on UNIX systems. But for Windows it's remain unconfigured. You need to configure from PHP.ini file.
For example:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.live.com
smtp_port = 25
username = my mail
password = my pass
```